# Authentication Failure Upon Successful Login

Tags: linux, gnome, authentication, screensaver, pam

I was reveiwing the logs when I was successful in logging into a workstation - however in the in the var/log/secure log it is logged as > gnome-screensaver-dialog:pam_unix(gnome-screensaver:auth): authentication failure;

Does anyone know why it logs it as authentication failure when it successfully logs me in? As a note it is logged the same way if i try to log in with an incorrect password with a not successful login.

Answer (score 0):

PAM supports multiple authentication attempts using different modules. In this case, the authentication failure is getting logged because the `pam_unix.so` module attempted and failed to authenticate you, but since you did eventually authenticate successfully, a different module must be listed after the `pam_unix.so` module in `/etc/pam.d/gnome-screensaver`.